# Response headers return text/html instead of application/json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux, mern

Making a full stack Todo app with the MERN stack and using Redux for state management. I'm trying to implement the edit functionality on my todos. App is pretty simple CRUD app for now. Double click on each todo to open an input field to edit, but when I submit, I get a 400 response with Bad Request error with the error message saying:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <first letter of my input> in JSON at position 0
```

Here is my action for the edit function:

```
//Edit todo
export const editTodo = (content, id) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/todos/${id}`, content, config);
    console.log(res.data);
    dispatch({
      type: EDIT_TODO,
      payload: res.data
    });

    dispatch(setAlert("Task Updated", "success"));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: TODO_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: error.response.data.msg, status: error.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

If I try to set the `"Content-Type": "application/json; charset-utf=8"` then my PUT request goes through but my "content" of `response.data` return null:

```
{isComplete: false, _id: "5d5e5eed3f1de13be7b58962", content: null, user: "5d5b8104e833fe17cf7d6ce2", date: "2019-08-22T09:22:53.577Z", …}
content: null
date: "2019-08-22T09:22:53.577Z"
isComplete: false
user: "5d5b8104e833fe17cf7d6ce2"
__v: 0
_id: "5d5e5eed3f1de13be7b58962"
__proto__: Object
```

I've tried `console.log(res.text)` to see why I'm getting the text/html returned but without the charset=utf-8, my PUT request fails with a 400 error and nothing is logged. Been stuck on this issue for a while now and have tried pretty much everything I can think of.

Here is the reducer with the initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  todos: [],
  todo: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_TODOS:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case ADD_TODO:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: [payload, ...state.todos],
        loading: false
      };
    case EDIT_TODO:
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: state.todos.map(todo =>
          todo._id === payload._id ? { ...todo, payload } : todo
        ),
        loading: false
      }
}
```

and here's my input and submit functions on the front-end:

```
const TaskItem = props => {
  const { todo, completeTodo, deleteTodo, editTodo } = props;

  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editVal, setEditVal] = useState(todo.content);

  const handleEditing = e => {
    setEditing(true);
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setEditVal(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleEditingDone = (e, id) => {
    console.log(id);
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      editTodo(editVal, id);
      setEditing(false);
    }
  };

  const viewStyle = {};
  const editStyle = {};

  if (editing) {
    viewStyle.display = "none";
  } else {
    editStyle.display = "none";
  }

  return (
    <Fade collapse bottom className={todo.isComplete ? "done" : ""}>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body className="justify-content-between">
          <div style={viewStyle} onDoubleClick={handleEditing}>
            <span
              className={editing ? "true" : ""}
              style={{
                textDecoration:
                  todo.isComplete === true ? "line-through" : "none"
              }}
            >
              <Form.Check
                onChange={() => completeTodo(todo._id)}
                data-id={todo._id}
                className="checkbox"
                inline
                label=""
                checked={todo.isComplete && "checked"}
                type="checkbox"
                id="inline-checkbox"
              />

              {todo.content}

              <button
                onClick={e => deleteTodo(todo._id)}
                className="action close "
                data-id={todo._id}
                type="button"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>

              <button type="button" className="action edit" data-id={todo._id}>
                <span aria-hidden="true">
                  <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt edit-icon" />
                </span>{" "}
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>

          <input
            data-id={todo._id}
            type="text"
            value={editVal || ""}
            style={editStyle}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onKeyDown={e => handleEditingDone(e, todo._id)}
          />
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </Fade>
  );
};

TaskItem.propTypes = {
  editTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default connect(
  null,
  { editTodo }
)(TaskItem);
```

I have read through all SO answers on this and tried using "use strict" on my api routes and none have been helpful. Any help will be appreciated.

My express route looks like this:

```
// @route   PUT api/todos/:id
// @desc    Update a todo
// @access  Private
router.put("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const todo = await Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $set: { content: req.body.content } },
      { new: true }
    );
    res.json(todo);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});
```

I have tested this on postman and it updates perfectly fine in the database as well.

Comment: Seems like the error has more to do with what your API is returning, the front-end looks fine. Can you share what your Express route looks like?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Edited the question to include my express route.

Comment: Hmm so when you tested with postman, does the response come back with an updated content value?

Comment: Yes, which is why I'm really confused and as you say my front-end looks fine so I don't even know where to start to fix this